# Pre transaction Rolling balance SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a couple of relatively straight forward tables (examples below).

One has accounts details in:

```
AccountNo     | CurrentBalance*         | ReferredBalance
12345         | £1254.25                | 1500.00
```

Current balance refreshes hourly so is not static

Another one has payments:

```
Accountno     | TranasctionNo   | TransDate   | Amount |
123456        | 558745489       | 01/01/2015  | £25.99 |
123456        | 558745490       | 01/02/2015  | £25.99 |
123456        | 558745491       | 01/02/2015  | £25.99 |
```

I’ve been tasked with keep a rolling balance based on payments received including a pre transaction amount.

So for example I need to an output to mirror :

```
AccountNo | TransactionDate | PreTransactionBalance | Amount | Current Balance|
123456    | 01/01/2015      | 1254.25               | 25.99  | 1228.26|
123456    | 01/02/2015      | 1228.26               | 25.99  | 1202.27|
123456    | 01/03/2015      | 1202.27               | 25.99  | 1176.28|
123456    | 01/03/2015      | 1176.28               | -100   | 1276.28|
```

I’ve added the negative in as it will need to calculate debits as well as credits.

Can't quiet work out how to get the rolling pre-transaction totals to work. Hopefully this is clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM(amount) OVER()` to get rolling `amount` based on the `TransactionNo` and then calculate pre transaction and current balance from this value.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @Account TABLE
(
AccountNo VARCHAR(10) ,
CurrentBalance MONEY,
ReferredBalance MONEY
)

DECLARE @AccountPayment TABLE
(
Accountno VARCHAR(10),TranasctionNo VARCHAR(10),TransDate DATE,Amount MONEY
)
insert into @Account VALUES
('12345','£1254.25','1500.00');

insert into @AccountPayment values
('12345','558745489','01/01/2015','£25.99'),
('12345','558745490','01/02/2015','£25.99'),
('12345','558745491','01/02/2015','£25.99'),
('12345','558745492','01/02/2015','-100');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT AP.AccountNo,
    TransDate,
    A.CurrentBalance - SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY TranasctionNo) + amount as PreTransactionBalance ,
    amount,
    A.CurrentBalance - SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY TranasctionNo) Current_Balance
FROM @AccountPayment AP
INNER JOIN @Account A
ON AP.Accountno = A.Accountno
```

**Edit**

It seems `ORDER BY` is not supported with in `SUM() OVER()` in SQL Server 2008 / SQL Server 2008 R2. As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> `ORDER BY Clause` cannot be used with aggregate window functions.

We can use `CROSS APPLY` like this.

```
SELECT AP.AccountNo,
    TransDate,
    A.CurrentBalance - pre_amount as PreTransactionBalance ,
    amount,
    A.CurrentBalance - pre_amount - amount Current_Balance
FROM @AccountPayment AP
INNER JOIN @Account A
ON AP.Accountno = A.Accountno
CROSS APPLY
(
     select ISNULL(sum(amount),0) as pre_amount 
     from @AccountPayment ap1 
     where ap1.Accountno = ap.Accountno and ap1.TranasctionNo < ap.TranasctionNo
 ) as b
```

**Output**

```
AccountNo   TransDate   PreTransactionBalance   amount  Prev_Payments
12345   2015-01-01  1254.25 25.99   1228.26
12345   2015-01-02  1228.26 25.99   1202.27
12345   2015-01-02  1202.27 25.99   1176.28
12345   2015-01-02  1176.28 -100.00 1276.28
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/074b2/4)

Comment: Thanks, trying to replicate this but get a sytax error "Incorrect syntax near 'order'" ? Cant stop the error?

Comment: Seems like your answer isnt supported in 2008?? but would work nicely in 2012.

Comment: `SUM(amount) OVER()` should work on [SQL Server 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: tried the updated answer however the Pretrans balance shows the same for all transaction (ie 1228.26 for all 4 trans). Its not aggregating it by the looks?